# GH001: Large files detected ----> master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: push, trace, large-files

I tried to push to my repository, but I had a file greater than 100 MB and GitHub and it displayed "GH001: Large files detected", so as I didn't need the file I removed it, updated with git add . and git commit, however the error still remains, as if the file would still be in the folder and as if I haven't add and commit after removing the file.

This is what's displayed:

```
[...]

Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (795/795), done.
Writing objects: 100% (800/800), 623.93 MiB | 5.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 800 (delta 104), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (104/104), completed with 42 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 34f648186732099e6b228feddefc1ba42161aef997a90e91e06aacda039596ea
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Podcast/Enrachados_21_10_2021.mp4 is 501.53 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:castorx9000/UnbettingFootball.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:castorx9000/UnbettingFootball.git'
```